# Is it possible to create a 'see through' mirror object

Tags: edit-mode

I have created a 'glass' object (eg a window) with metallic = 1 and roughness = 0 and alpha = 0.2 and blend mode set to alpha blend which results in the glass being see through as well as reflecting the 'environment' but wondering if it is possible to have a glass a see through glass object which also reflects nearby objects. When the blend mode is changed from opaque to alpha blend the reflection of nearby objects is lost and only the 'environment' reflection remains.

I am trying to 'imitate' a full glass cabinet (seen in museums) which can be seen through but also (partially) reflects nearby people.

Answer (score 3):

just try using alpha hashed instead of alpha blend.

i got this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes that works but leaves a 'speckled' look (tiny white spots).

Comment: alpha hashed is always a bit more noisy option, it will make those dots that you want but maybe denoiser can solve it?

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if I am applying denoise correctly even after watching a video tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iD1Y1D-KTMI). I changed to Cycles and denoising render to NLM then selected the RENDER 'button' (top of viewport) and didn't see anything but maybe I wouldn't as it is glass. My (original - no denoise) blender file is at https://mega.nz/file/38IEiQRB#S-O8hGs14s8XZjc5_F7gkhoD6gQwAEjzCA3CzWmTROg